# Why does Java Graphics not work with custom sub classes?

Tags: java, graphics2d

I am trying to create a subclass just for circles using the Ellipse2D.Double class.

```
public class Circle extends Ellipse2D.Double{

double radius;

public Circle (double radius){
        radius = this.radius;
        height = radius*2;
        width = radius*2;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
}
```

Filling the JPanel like so does not work:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        Circle circle1 = new Circle(100);

        g2.draw(circle1);
```

but doing it like so does work:

```
g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 100, 100));
```

why is this ? I am setting all the fields from Ellipse2D in the constructor and i am not getting any error messages. So i am not sure why it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor is incorrect.

```
        radius = this.radius;
```

is setting the parameter variable `radius` to the initial value of the `radius` field.  It should be the other way around.

```
        this.radius = radius;
```